# kernel panic in Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, kernel-panic

I'm not good in English!!

my friend has Windows 11 and Debian seed, dual boot on his laptop, today he decide to add an HDD to his laptop. when Windows is hibernated he opened the laptop and add the HDD.

he can boot to windows but when he try to boot Debian he got this screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on the HDD?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon No, just installed HDD. laptop have two SSD, one for windows and another for Debian.

Comment: Have you tried to change order of ssd disk ?

Comment: The picture identifies the hardware as ["LENOVO 81Y4"](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-gaming-3-15imh05/81y4/documentation/doc_userguide). The [Hardware Maintenance Manual for it](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_gaming3_hmm_202004.pdf) indicates only one SSD slot and one HDD slot. Is it possible that the second SSD was installed to the HDD slot with an adapter, and was removed when the HDD was added?

Comment: @Ben He says "yes", order has changed!!

Comment: @telcoM No, Laptop has 2 m2 slots and both SSDs installed on m2 port

Answer (score 0):

On the first line in the picture, the system has done a filesystem check on `/dev/nvme0n1p2` and it has been successful.

On the second line, `init[1]` reports a segmentation fault in `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

I think that means the system is just transitioning off initramfs and to the real root filesystem when the error occurs. But it worries me that the system seems to have found `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` but reports a segmentation fault in it... that suggests either file corruption or some sort of data transfer error.

To troubleshoot, you probably need to boot from Debian installation media in rescue mode.

Things to check while in rescue mode:

- `/dev/nvme*` devices and the partitioning on each device - a hardware configuration change may have changed the detection order. `lsblk -o +uuid` might be a good command here.
- `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/default/grub` - if there are `/dev/nvme*` references, make sure they point to the correct disks. If disk ordering has changed, you might have to run `update-grub` and `update-initramfs -u -k <kernel version>` for each installed kernel version. Generally, you should be using `UUID=` references to filesystems instead of device names, to allow the system to easily deal with hardware configuration changes.

When you say "Debian seed", do you mean Debian "Sid"? That is the unstable development version of the Debian distribution: if your friend uses that, he should be prepared to deal with things breaking occasionally.